# how do I find the latest index in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, blockchain

I'm making a blockchain application in GoLang using mongodb and mongodb compass.
When a node that is connected to the the system is disconnected, I want it to reconnect with the block of the latest index and hash in the blockchain. How can I get this index? I'm not sure if this is too vague

Answer (score 0):

To find the latest index of docs in a collection.

```
db.collection_name.find().sort('_id',pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(limit)
```

Comment: I'm getting  "2020-01-24T04:09:12.026-0500 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: ReferenceError: pymongo is not defined :" as an error message. What does pymongo do?

Comment: Hi! PyMongo is the Python driver. "pymongo.DESCENDING" translates to just "-1", it's used to sort in descending order: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.DESCENDING